# What is the rationale for modern pronunciation of Latin in music?

Tags: pronunciation, song-lyrics, music

I'm not particularly versed in musical tradition, but I've been aware for some time now that the modern de-facto standard for pronouncing Latin in singing is what is commonly referred to as the "Ecclesiastical" pronunciation.  Now, this makes sense in a purely Roman Catholic context, but it also seems to be standard quite outside of that.  So, in the well-known Christmas carol "Angels we have heard on high", the Latin phrase *Gloria in excelsis Deo* is pronounced (as far as I've observed) more or less as [ɡloːːːːː::::ria in ɛksʧɛlsis deːoː].  But, why?

My understanding (perhaps erroneous) is that the Italianate Latin pronunciation became standard for the RC church only in the 19th century, so why has it now become normal for singing in Latin universally, outside of a RC context?

Quite apart from the Christmas-tide "gloria in excelsis Deo", I recently heard a rendition of Carl Orff's musical version of a Latin mediaeval poem from *Carmina Burana*, *O Fortuna*, and was struck by the consistent modern Ecclesiastical pronunciations, e.g., *glaciem* as [ɡlɑʧiɛm].  Assuming that a restored Classical/republican pronunciation of [ɡlɑkiɛm] would be considered inappropriate for the time-period, and that the *Carmina Burana* was a collection of a *German* mediaeval Latin poems, wouldn't [ɡlɑtsiɛm] be more appropriate?  (At any rate, I find the Italian pronunciation rather off-putting in the context.)

---

A final postscript:  Although what I've *heard* is that *excelsis* is pronounced in the Christmas carol as [ɛksʧɛlsis], wouldn't [ɛkʃɛlsis] be the "correct" Ecclesiastical pronunciation?

Comment: For the final question: no, because "x" in Italian and in E. Latin is pronounced [ks] and "c" before "e" or "i" is [ʧ]. Being one after the other, they're just added up together.

Comment: @VincenzoOliva: Hmm.  I'm not sure I quite agree with that logic.  Note that _sceleris_ is pronounced [ʃɛlɛris], so if <sce> is pronounced [ʃɛ] rather than  [sʧɛ]. should not <xce> (equivalent to <csce>) be pronounced [kʃɛ] by the same logic?

Comment: With the last remark of my first comment I didn't mean "because they're one after the other". I stated a rule: _when_ they are one after the other, the're just added up together, i.e. "xc" before "e" or "i" is always pronounced [ksʧ]. As you noted, this is not the case for "sc", which in these cases is [ʃ] and not [sk].

Comment: In Germany and parts East, a different pronunciation is current for Church Latin, one less influenced by Italiian. [ɡlɑtsiɛm], for example.

Comment: Anyway, the answer is tradition and taste, though I don't know if this can be _made_ into an answer. I remember reading discussions about this, where many said to favour the softer sounds of Italianate Latin, sometimes in view of "more intimacy with God" - typically considering _veni, vidi, vici_, in fact. Being Italian I also prefer these sounds, but I opt to be (more) faithful to how the Romans spoke around 200 AD.

Comment: If you can get your hands on it, I found "Singing in Latin" by Harold Copeman to be a good read. However, from what I remember, it is more focused on evidence about earlier traditions of pronunciation, so I don't know whether it covers the spread of Italianate pronunciation to areas where it wasn't originally common

Comment: @sumelic: from Amazon beginning at $1368 for hardcover and from $349 for paperback!  I'm going to resist the urge to purchase it!

Comment: @VincenzoOliva:  with respect to _excelsis_, I've just come across this [reference](http://cmed.faculty.ku.edu/rehnotes/latin.html) that supports the [ɛkʃɛlsis] pronunciation.  (I won't claim it is definitive.)

Comment: @varro: Nope, that's wrong. Wiktionary gives the correct E. pronunciation of e.g. [_excelsus_](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/excelsus).

Comment: @sumelic I'll create a separate question for that.

Comment: @sumelic: It is, nowadays, the only correct Italianate pronunciation, which is normally the standard for E. Latin. I never said it has _always_ been so, I couldn't easily back up that claim. Your find is interesting, though I think the French substratum plays a role in that (the _Liber Usualis_ was compiled by the monks of the Abbey of Solesmes in France).

Comment: You will certainly find examples of music with other pronunciations https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XVLDd9FhC-w

Answer (score 1):

I agree with your view that the Carmina Burana should be pronounced as if it were German. Until the late 19th century, European schools and universities taught Latin pronunciation in local styles following the dominant language. This is why native English speakers say "Julius Caesar" in a way that would be incomprehensible to the man himself. This approach to Latin pronunciation is still preserved in English legal phrases such as "sine die".

Hence it is likely that the authors of the Carmina Burana pronounced Latin as if it were Hochdeutsch, subject to the proviso that the authors may not have been Bavarians even though the poems were found at Benediktbeuern. Mediaeval clerics did move around, however, so it is possible that the authors were not German speakers.

Comment: “pronounced Latin as if it were Hochdeutsch” – uhm, but what does that mean? How would we pronounce *glaciem* “if it were” Middle High German?

Comment: I am no expert in MHG so I suggest you consult a guide to MHG pronunciation. From the little I remember, the only variation from Hochdeutsch in "glaciem" would be to pronounce the '"c" as /k/. At a guess, the "ie" would be taught as following the Latin, but it may well have been sounded as the monophthong /i/.

Comment: But the pronunciation "glakiem" is definitely not how *glaciem* was pronounced in medieval Germany. It would be the reconstructed pronunciation that (as you correctly point out) appeared no earlier than the 19th century and would be out of place in a medieval song.

Comment: Compare German loan words like Zisterne (from *cisterna*) or Kreuz (MHG kriuz, from *crux, crucis*). As a matter of fact, that we say Kiste (OHG kista, MHG kiste, from *cista*) is seen as proof that it must be a very early borrowing (3rd century or so).

Answer (score -1):

*Angels we have heard on high* is an English carol, so *gloria in excelsis Deo* should be pronounced as in English.

Comment: Neither an English nor a Latin carol.  French.  The original is *Les anges dans nos campagnes*.

Comment: @Monsour If you sing it French, you should use French pronunciation. I assumed the question is why do we pronounce it like English when we sing it English.

Comment: If you sing a French carol partly in English and partly in Latin, you could just as well say you should pronounce the English as though it were Latin.  In the real world, there are customs about how Latin is sung that aren't reducible to such trite statements.  To take an example from using French words in English, surely you don't pronounce *hors d'oeuvres* as though it were English.