# the pronunciation of _excelsis_ in Ecclesiastical Latin

Tags: pronunciation, ecclesiastical-latin

In [another post](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/8781/what-is-the-rationale-for-modern-pronunciation-of-latin-in-music) about the de-facto standard use of Ecclesiastical Latin pronunciation in singing, I included a postscript querying whether *excelsis* should be pronounced [ɛksʧɛlsis] or [ɛkʃɛlsis].  There seems to some doubt about the matter; what I've typically heard is the former, but the latter seems to be supported by at least some references.  *Is* there anything that can claim to give an authoritative answer, or is it simply a matter of taste?

Comment: Not (completely) authoritative, but FWIW, here's St. John XXIII [singing Gloria in excelsis](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=LATEEHITZUo). 1. He was Italian. 2. At the time, it was common to follow Ecclesiastical (graduate) studies in Latin. The sound is not too clear. Judge by yourselves. IMHO there is anything but a /s/ sound: it could be either [ɛk'ʧɛl.sis] (would be weird) or [ɛk'ʃɛl.sis]

Comment: @Rafael: Provided that I do think the sound is unclear, I hear [ksʧ]. I've shown it to some people I know, one of which has sung in a church choir, and they also agree. Apart from that, I am particularly confident it's there at 0:15 [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k1yd9JhLPyM). The singer (as well as director of the ensemble, called _Stirps Iesse_), [Enrico De Capitani](https://www.scuoladicantogregoriano.it/?ID=344), is not a pope, but he has studied Gregorian Chant and is a stable member of the group _Cantori Gregoriani_. [continues]

Comment: As I mention in my answer, I believe any deviation from [ksʧ] is either due to regional tradition (e.g. the _Liber Usualis_ builds on a French substratum) or personal taste of a specific director, as I've come to know some directors (perhaps also in Italy, but I don't know of any) choose to avoid the /s/ sound, and opt for a softer [kʃ].

Comment: @VincenzoOliva I'm no expert at all, I just think I remember being taught that xc=ksc>[kʃ], i.e., x being one letter didn't prevent simplification involving one of the constituent sounds. *You are probably right*, but I can't be convinced by the Italian=Ecclesiastical argument. The latter is strongly based on the former, undoubtedly, but there are differences (e.g. _mihi_), and 'xc' does not occur naturally in Italian. Consonant cluster simplification is (almost) a constant throughout Latin history

Comment: @Rafael: Sure enough, I get your perspective and you make good points. Anyway from what I've gathered, independently of what _should_ be the pronunciation of the word, the way the singers actually deal with it greatly varies from choir to choir, as well as from individual to individual, and any of the options seems to be acceptable. At the end of the day, at least in singing, the difference is not that significant.

Comment: @Rafael: Is *mihi* no longer pronounced as /miki/ in the context of Italian? I thought that was both the Italian and the Ecclesiastical Latin pronunciation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most authoritative source I've found so far is the [English rubrics](https://sanctamissa.org/en/music/gregorian-chant/choir/liber-usualis-1961.pdf) for the [Liber usualis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liber_Usualis).

In *Rules for interpretation > IX. The reading and pronunciation of liturgical Latin > Consonants* (page xxxvii / 37 in the pdf linked) it reads:

> **SC** before the same vowels [a, ae, oe, i, y] is pronounced like *Sh* in *shed*,

which we already knew. Then, the interesting part is on the next page:

> **XC** before e, ae, oe, i, y - **KSH**.
>                                                       e.g. **Excelsis** = *ek-shel-sees*.
>   Before others vowels **XC**  has the ordinary hard  sound  of the letters composing it
>                                                       e.g. **excussórum** =  *eks-coos-so-room*.

I'm not aware of a more authoritative source than the Liber usualis regarding Ecclesiastical Latin (though there could be, e.g. in the Missal or some decree/motu proprio). BUT, there could be more details in the Latin version of the rubrics, which I haven't been able to find yet.

**Update/Note:** I plan to ask someone more knowledgeable than me (perhaps even a 70-something priest) about the authority level of the Liber usualis. But currently I think that even if it was not officially *lex orandi* (I'm not sure about that), it was very widespread in the decades prior to the Second Vatican Council and the liturgical reform (the linked edition is from 1961). At that time Ecclesiastical pronunciation was already in effect, and unity and authority were taken in a seriously formal way in the Church. Personally, I doubt the editors would have been willing to add their own personal taste to the detriment of unity, but I could be mistaken.

---

**Bonus track**: the rule for TI literally reads:

> **TI** standing before a vowel and following any letter (except S, X, T) is pronounced *tsee*.
>   Otherwise the **T** is like the English *T*.

Therefore, **commixtio** > [com'miks.ti.o]! Anyway, the wording makes me very uneasy because English [t] is aspirated and I've always assumed Latin [t] is not. I just hope the distinction was omitted for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: That -tti- exception is odd. I can find very few words that it would apply to: *muttio,* and then some proper nouns such as *Brattia,Sittius, Cottius.*

Comment: In the context of English, I've read that non-palatalization of "tiV" also often occurred in some words/names from Greek: https://books.google.com/books?id=dFQEAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA2

Comment: After due consideration, I've decided to accept @Rafael's citation of the _Liber Usualis_ as about as authoritative as one can get.  (I do *not* accept the idea that its pronunciation guidelines somehow reflect a "French substratum".)  There's no doubt that _excelsis_ is commonly pronounced as [ɛksʧɛlsis] (which is no doubt why Wiktionary reflects that pronunciation, but Wiktionary, in my opinion, cannot be regarded as authoritative).

Comment: Note that I *am* impressed with @VincenzoOliva's citation of Enrico de Capitani's clear pronunciation of [ɛksʧɛlsis].  But of course, individual choirs are not necessarily bound to follow LU's recommendations, and apparently don't.

Comment: @varro: I think you should address my updated answer and sumelic's one.

Comment: @VincenzoOliva: my apologies for not responding sooner - the fact is that I've been distracted lately.  In *do* intend to read the additional references you have supplied, and respond accordingly, but right now I just want to assure you that I'm *not* just ignoring your request, and hope to have a well-thought response in the near future.

Comment: @varro: I see, no worries! Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @VincenzoOliva: Thank you for the reference - I have read the entire thing (despite my Spanish being a bit rusty).  This does seem, though, to be another data point that's interesting, but not authoritative.  In particular, it seems to approach the manner of pronunciation from a *very* Spanish perspective.  I was surprised (e.g.) to see a pronunciation [léyem] (IPA ['lɛjɛm]) for Latin _legem_.  (continued...)

Comment: @VincenzoOliva:  (contˈd) In fact, it seems to treat Spanish pronunciation(s) on an equal footing with the Italian pronunciation.  (But "soft" G is still pronounced "[y]" IPA [j] rather than [dʒ], and _ecce_ is pronounced "[ékche]" IPA [ˈɛkʧɛ] rather than [ˈɛtʧɛ]?.)  I will admit, though, it supports the idea that [kʧɛ] is now a _de facto_ standard for _xce_, and sumelic's addendum would also seem to support that.  So, I guess I can now sing [ˈɡloria in ɛks'ʧɛlsis deo] with a clear conscience.

Comment: @varro: Sure,the author comes from a Spanish perspective -it's an "Aragonese Journal of Musicology".But while he rightly comments on the validity of any local pronunciation if a piece of music is historically related to it, he does state the Italian pronunciation (mostly) coincides with the Ecclesiastical one, reminding the reader of the recommendations of Pope Pius X.Also, note that on pages 86 and 89 Ramiro explains his phonetic notation:his [y] is "sonido palatal africado sonoro,y en cast. yo, reyes; **(omitting the wrong _yard_ example)**; g en it. àngelo", i.e. IPA [dʒ],correctly; (cont.)

Comment: @varro: (... continued) as for -_cce_- , which he transcribes as [kche], it probably is a mistake indeed (though I'm not totally sure, his notation is terrible). However, he published several notable papers and the journal has national relevance, so I don't find the reference unauthoritative. Anyway, I'm glad you'll have a clear conscience while singing _Gloria in excelsis Deo_ !

Answer (score 5):

From the other question, it seems you agree that starting from the end of the 19th century, after the recommendations of Pope Pius X, the Italian pronunciation became the standard one for E. Latin. If you do, then the way [*excelsior*](https://www.dizionario-italiano.it/dizionario-italiano.php?lemma=EXCELSIOR100) (a loan word) is pronounced in Italian answers your question - [ksʧ], and indeed Wiktionary abides by such standard for the Ecclesiastical pronunciation of [*excelsus*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/excelsus). If instead you don't make this assumption, then it depends on taste and geography.

**UPDATE**:  In agreement with @sumelic's contribution, I've finally got an article that confirms the recommended pronunciation to be the Italian one, i.e. [ksʧ]:

*Pronunciación de los textos latinos puestos en música. Estudio práctico para la interpretación de
la música española* (Pronunciation of Latin texts put to music. Practical study for the interpretation of Spanish music) published by [Francisco Javier Estrada Ramiro](https://dialnet.unirioja.es/servlet/autor?codigo=2492960) on *Nassarre : Revista aragonésa de musicología*, ISSN 0213-7305, Vol. 24, Nº 1, 2008, pages 59-96.

It is available [here](https://ifc.dpz.es/recursos/publicaciones/28/97/03estrada.pdf), in Spanish. On page 77 one may read

> Algunos han postulado dos pronunciaciones en el latín a la italiana: la clásica del siglo I, hasta el s. III d. C., y la italiana a partir de dicho siglo, por ejemplo para los textos de San Agustín.
>
> A principios del s. XX, desde el papado se recomendó el uso de esta pronunciación para todo el mundo. Sus rasgos distintivos, con respecto a la clásica, son:
>
> - Los diptongos ae, oe se pronuncian e (Ecclesiae: [ecclésie]).
> - Los grupos ce, ci, cae, coe, suenan palatales oclusivos sordos (**Caeci**lia: [**Chechí**lia]), aunque en la Edad Media sonaba más bien [ts], asibilación, así como el grupo ti más vocal.
> - De manera análoga, los grupos ge, gi, gy , – gae, goe, muy escasos –, palatales oclusivos sonoros (legem: [léyem]; gymnasia: [yimnásia]).
> - El Grupo gn resulta una ñ española si no va a principio de palabra (agnus: [añus]; pero gnosis: [gnosis]).
> - La s sonora intervocálica y sorda inicial o tras consonante.
> - Los grupos sce, sci, scae, scoe, suenan palatales fricativos ([∫] ch en
>   francés, sh en inglés; suscipe: [sú∫ipe]). Y **los grupos xce, xci, xcae, xcoe, suenan sch (excelsis: [ekschelsis])**.

where I have highlighted the bit we're interested in - and the example of *Caecilia* and how it's pronounced, to show that the author doesn't use the IPA, and in particular writes [ch] for the usual [ʧ].

---

**As an aside**, the penultimate listed feature (intervocalic -s- being always pronounced [z]) is supposedly inherited from *neostandard* Italian ("New Standard" Italian), which coexists with Standard Italian without threatening to replace it. For the record, Standard Italian has various exceptions to the voiced intervocalic sibilant, and Southern Italian has *only* the voiceless one, maintaining the Classical Latin pronunciation. This begs the question: did Ecclesiastical Latin really pick up this Northern Italian feature?

Phonologically, the "New Standard" picks up some Northern Italian contemporary peculiarities, as opposed to literary Tuscan-Florentine being the model for Standard Italian. There is a question about this on Italian.SE, [here](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/10267/la-pronuncia-standard-dellitaliano-%C3%A8-effettivamente-cambiata-ed-in-particolare/10316?noredirect=1#comment24101_10316). Denis Nardin's answer quotes some excerpts in English from *The Italian Language Today*. The authors are Anna Laura Lepschy and Giulio Lepschy, both Northern Italian.

Comment: Regarding your latest edit, there is another question on this site that asks about the pronunciation of intervocalic S in Latin: [Is “s” between two vowels voiced or unvoiced?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/2904/is-s-between-two-vowels-voiced-or-unvoiced) As I say in my answer there, I wasn't able to find any clear definite pattern for "Ecclesiastical Latin"; it's interesting to see that Estrada Ramiro recommends voicing intervocalic S.

Answer (score 2):

I just came across some old notes I took when reading Harold Copeman's *Singing in Latin: Or Pronunciation Explor'd* (unfortunately, I forget which edition it was).

In the section on Ecclesiastical/Italian Latin, Copeman says that xci/xce traditionally had /kʃ/ (I'm not sure exactly what that means, or on what basis he makes this statement*), but that "In Italian literary Latin xc is x-c, [kstʃ]. I understand that this is now generally preferred in singing; [ktʃ] is acceptable and [kʃ] is not recognized" (p.228). This agrees with what Vincenzo Oliva says in the comments and in his answer.

---

*As Rafael says in his answer, at least some editions of the *Liber Usualis* give [kʃ]. Here is a link to the [English translation of the 1957 *Liber Usualis*](http://www.ccwatershed.org/media/pdfs/13/08/14/14-39-54_0.pdf), which gives [kʃ] as the pronunciation of "**XC** before the sounds of **E** and **I**" (p. xxij).